# ¿Cómo puedo compartir código C# en un script API de UFT?

Tags: c#

He creado un código en C# con una función que obtiene un NIF aleatorio para mi script API de UFT.

El código C# que he creado lo he guardado en la carpeta USerCode de UFT(en un archivo con extensión `.CS`), para que sea accesible para todas las activities de mi script.

Quisiera poder reutilizar este código por otros scripts API de la misma manera que se pueden compartir funciones escritas en [visualbasic](/questions/tagged/visualbasic) utilizando las librerías de funciones en los Scripts GUI de UFT.

Todos mis scripts se almacenan en ALM (Application Lifecycle Management) y, para reutilizar el código, pensé en almacenar el archivo `.CS` también en ALM. Así lo podría asociar a todos mis scritps API, pero UFT no me deja almacenar el archivo `.CS` en ALM, ni tampoco añadir ningún archivo alojado en ALM a la carpeta `USerCode` de UFT.

Necesito encontrar alguna forma de compartir funciones en los scripts de la API de UFT.